# "Not so straightforward a question

Tags: word-choice

What is the name of this construction? Is it old-fashioned and formal?

"It's not so straightforward a question."

Comment: What are your doubts, Antonia?

Comment: ... an where did you see it? Can you please provide a complete paragraph containing this sentence, ideally with a link to the complete document?

Comment: Not old-fashioned or formal at all. "It's not that crazy an idea."

Comment: sigh... English grammar is not as straightforward as it might be.

Comment: @Ronald Sole, what kind of construction is it? What is the difference between the original sentence and this one: "It's not a straightforward question"?

Comment: **So** simply modifies **straightforward**.  It's the difference between saying **it's not easy** and **it's not so easy**. It implies the degree of ease/straightforwardness concerned.